# All properties of intent.putExtra to crop image in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, crop

I'm creating an app where the user will use the camera or choose some photos from the gallery.

I'm trying to put some rules when the user chooses the photo from the album but I don't know all the properties and I tried to search some site or tutorial but I didn't found anything.

Someone knows where I can find this or learn the properties.

Properties like this

```
intent.putExtra("crop","true");
intent.putExtra("aspectX",10);
intent.putExtra("aspectY",10);
intent.putExtra("outputX",256);
intent.putExtra("outputY",256);
intent.putExtra("return-data",true);
```

I need to disable the resize function from the crop screen and I want to learn more about working with an android camera.

Thanks and regards to everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"return-data"
"cropped-rect"
"aspectX"
"aspectY"
"spotlightX"
"spotlightY"
"outputX"
"outputY"
"scale"
"data"
"scaleUIfNeeded"
"outputFormat"
"set-as-wallpaper"
"noFaceDetection"

Answer (score 1):

I refer you to Mr. Murphy's post here: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html